# Confused between 'to' and 'in'

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence-
*Information failure occurs when one party **to** an economic transaction possesses greater material knowledge than the other party.*

Shouldn't we use **'in'** rather than **'to'** highlighted above? And why/why not?

Comment: Prepositions are idiomatic, so hard to explain. *To* is the standard one here, though *in* does also work. Party to a lawsuit, party to a disagreement, party to the trickery.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/be-a-party-to-something-be-party-to-something

Comment: "why" questions like this are generally unanswerable. It's just the way it is.

Comment: Being _party to a transaction_ is a legal phrase with a specific meaning. It's not a matter of English grammar, since the meaning is determined by courts. And, like all fixed phrases, you can't mix'n'match prepositions.